# Unexpected cannot read property of undefined even after defining Partial<T>

Tags: typescript

I have a function where I am trying to normalize certain values. I have declared the whole function type as Partial but still I am getting the error Cannot read property `endTime` of undefined.

Here is my function:

```
export function mapOptionsToEditActivity<T extends InteractionType>(
    interaction: Partial<InteractionTypeInteractionMap[T]>,
    interactionType: T,
    matchedRecord: InteractionMatchedRecord,
    user: User,
    activityId: string,
): Partial<CrmInteraction> {
    const mappedInteraction = {
        crmCallId: activityId,
        dateEnd: interaction.endTime,
        dateStart: interaction.startTime,
        userCrmId: user.crmId,
    };

    return mappedInteraction; 
}
```

As you can see in the above code I have declared interaction as Partial Type and also the whole function type as Partial.

But I am getting this error

`Cannot read property endTime of undefined`

Can someone please help me identify where I am doing wrong?

Comment: partial makes properties optional that means they can be undefined. Either remove partial or replace interaction.endTime with interaction?.endTime

Comment: your problem is that `interaction` is undefined, ergo it has no `endTime` property, you could try `interaction?.endTime` this says try to get endTime but if it doesn't exists return undefined

Answer (score 1):

i think you are misunderstanding what partial is for

```
interface foo
{
    bar:string
}
```

in this case

```
const a:foo = {} //this will error because foo needs a bar fields

const b:foo = {bar:"123"} //so this will work

const c:foo = undefined // this will also error as c is of type foo not undefined

const x:Partial<foo> = {} //this will work because a Partial<foo> may or may not have a bar fields

const y:Partial<foo>= {bar:"123"} //so this will work as well

const z:Partial<foo>= undefined // this will still error though as undefined is not a foo


const u:foo|undefined = undefined  // this will work as u can bee foo or undefined
```

likewise typescript knows

```
b.bar //will always work because it can't be a foo unless its has a bar

x.bar //this may or not work because a partial foo may not have a bar so you need to check for undefined before its safe to use

u.bar //with this one u itself may be undefined so you need to check for undefined before even worrying about the property
```

there are many ways to do this is typescript

```
if(u) u.bar;
```

typescript knows you can't get inside the if unless u is not undefined so therefore it must be a foo

```
if("bar" in u) u.bar;
```

if bar is present then no issue accessing it

```
u?.bar // short hand for if(u) return u.bar; else return undefined;
```

check if there is a bar property and return it if so else return undefined;

```
u!.bar
```

ignore the type checking because you know something the compiler doesn't and the undefined will never happen

however the key thing to remember here is that typescript doesn't actually run, it is compiled in the plain js, which doesn't actually care if you have followed typescripts rule, so it is easy for external data that the typescript would know breaks all the rules you have set to getting to the compiled javascript and break everything

Comment: Thanks! I was actually trying to avoid an optional operator. But I guess that's the only way.